# Using C# Parallel.ForEach to replace out most loop when dealing with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, entity-framework-6, thread-safety

I have a C# console application. The application requires me to parse data from text files that are stored in Windows folders, to insert or update the extracted data into SQL Server tables, and to log summary info to an external common log file. I am using Entity Framework v6.2 and a `DbContext` class to manipulate the data. Each person owns different folders and each folder stores multiple data text files.

At the moment, the application uses a **synchronous** approach using `foreach` loops. Please see the below Approach 1.

However, I am afraid that if I use synchronous programming then when I release the app to production server, it can cause performance issues such as slowed running. So, I plan to replace my synchronous codes with C# `Parallel.ForEach` approach.

**My question:** is it better and safe to use C# `Parallel.ForEach` statement instead of using my current synchronous code?

Thank you for your help.

Details of what I am doing and planning to do.

**Approach 1**: Synchronous for the outermost loop that uses C# regular `foreach`

```
public void Process(List<Person> people)
{
    // Note: each person has multiple folders
    // Each folder has multiple text files that are parsed in insert/update to SQL server database tables

    try
    {
        // Notes: 
        // _people variable is of type List<Person>
        // MyDbContext is of type C# Entity Framework DbContext

        // Note: one DbContext-typed context is used for all loops

        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // Note: at present, I am using  C# regular foreach lopp to iterate all persons in People collection variable 

            foreach (var person in people) // Note: this is the outmost loop and it makes synchronous execution
            {
                // Note: FolderSerivce is an helper class that uses C# DbContext-typed MyDbContext as above and person object to read folder rows in database for each person.

                var folders = new FolderService(context, person);
                var personName = person.Name;


                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    var myParserAndInsert = new ParserAndInsert();
                    // Note: Dowork() method is used to parse all files of a folder and insert/update data to databse using EF "context" (DbContext typed" and to log summary to an external common log file).
                    myParserAndInsert.Dowork(context, folder); 
                }
            }
        }
       ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**: I plan to use `Parallel.ForEach` to replace the outermost loop that is the loop to iterate through all persons in the `List<Person>`-type people variable as it is in approach 1.

```
public void Process(List<Person> people)
{
    // Note: each person has multiple folders
    // Each folder has multiple text files that are parsed in insert/update to SQL server database tables

    try
    {
        // Notes: 
        // _people variable is of type List<Person>
        // MyDbContext is of type C# Entity Framework DbContext

        Parallel.ForEach(people, person =>
        {
            // Note: context is re-created for each person
            using (var context = new MyDbontext())
            {
                var folders = new FolderService(context, person);                            

                foreach (var folder in folders)
                {
                    var myParserAndInsert = new ParserAndInsert();

                    // Note: Dowork() method is used to parse all files of a folder and insert/update data to databse using EF "context" (DbContext typed" and to log summary to an external common log file).

                    myParserAndInsert.Dowork(context, folder); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ll have to measure and benchmark. Creating new contexts, possible synchronization inside EF etc may very well make all this worthless or even slower

Comment: **Yes and No.** `Parallel.ForEach` is not always faster and in some cases it is slower because of the overhead of context switching. If it was better then the creators of the .NET Framework will make regular loops obsolete. Do not use them if you do not know how they work. Ask your company to give you a machine which has similar configuration (memory, disk) etc so you can do your performance benchmarking on it. If that is not an option, use math to do benchmarking. Or put it in production and wait until someone complains about the performance and then fix that specific bottleneck.